# Running tensorflow on Playstation4

Tags: linux

Can tensorflow run on Playstation 4. I googled it, but not much information has been added.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python can run on the Play Station 4. Tensorflow can run in Python. So, yes, Tensorflow can run on the Play Station 4.

Comment: How do I run python in PS4? I believe with the linux hack for PS4, someone can find on google, right?

Comment: I don't know the exact method, I just know it's possible. Head over to Stack Overflow if you encounter issues.

Answer (score 1):

PS4 has AMD GCN 2.0 architecture. ( https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/playstation-4-gpu.c2085 )
But not exactly. They bypass L1 / L2 cache to have direct memory access.

AMD ROC'm driver:
https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm
https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Deep_learning/Deep-learning.html

So in theory it is likely to be possible.

It is can do 1.8TFlops (300 USD), which is a bit better then NVidia Jetson TX2 (475 USD) 1.3 TFlops.

So in theory it is possible and worth but due to the fact that I haven't seen any sign of success on the internet, I have my doubts if the ROCm driver can be installed w/o problems on PS4. But I am also curious if someone managed to do this.